# Серая или теневая

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые перед "или" и после "теневая": "Серая" или "теневая"зарплата -это...

Comment: "Серая" и "теневая" кавычками лучше не выделять. См. http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/29_322263

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь запятые нужны. Без этого непонятно, что "теневая" поясняет "серая". Т.е. получается, что "серая" и "теневая" - два разных вида "зарплаты".

Насчет кавычек - факультативны. Вернее сказать - от контекста. Если термины понятны, то кавычки не нужны. Но с другой стороны, если понятны, зачем пояснение? Так что можете, думаю, оставить, если автор настаивает.

Comment: Спасибо за консультацию.

Answer (score 2):

> Нужны ли запятые...

НУЖНА запятая перед ***или.***

=====

Гм... Похоже, нужна запятая и после ***теневая.***

См. у Розенталя (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=119 ):

> **§ 23...**
>
> 2. Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом ***или*** (‘то есть’):   <...>
>
>    *Отметим два вида **возбуждающей, или входной,** функции.*

Comment: здесь союз или равен то есть? Теневая можно считать вторым названием серой? Что-то я никак не разберусь, в каком значении выступает союз или?

Comment: "здесь союз или равен то есть?" === ДА.

Comment: А мне кажется, что этот вид зарплаты просто имеет два названия: серая и теневая. В газетных текстах называют зарплату в конверте то серая, то теневая, значит, эти названия равноправны, тогда получается, что запятые не нужны?

Comment: "эти названия равноправны". === Как раз поэтому-то запятые и нужны.

Comment: Может, лучше так написать: _Серая (теневая) зарплата -- это..._ (?)

Comment: Я уж думала над таким вариантом. Спасибо.